# Caching requests in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

When a browser does XHR requests it uses a cache that works with headers like `max-age` etc. to minimize the number of requests.

I'm wondering if there's a node library or so that reads these headers for requests to other servers and implements caching for them, at least in-memory, as long as the node script runs.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This might help you! - https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-cache-controller

Comment: @DavidR — That does the opposite of what the question is asking for.

Comment: But, as per the documentation, it does allow the user to set maxAge, sMax Age etc.

Comment: As far as I understand, that module really does the opposite of what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the best solution to my problem is the library [make-fetch-happen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-fetch-happen?).